# Search and Pagination Functions not working in DataTable when using Dynamic Data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

I made a table and I have been using Datatable CDN to have some functions such as search and the ability to select table pages. After following the steps on DataTables my code load my table with the search bar and pages, however all the functions are not working. Can someone tell me where I did a mistake please:

Using static data makes the dataTable work as it is intended with the search option and pagination working and showing the results that are in the table. However when using dynamic data with MySQL database the search and pagination functions stops working. Below is my code with fetch the data from table employees from my DB:

```
<?php
     global $db;
     $sql = "SELECT id, name, role, competency FROM employees";
     $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
?>
```

This query is found just before my table in my html code, all the data are displayed correctly and styling of dataTable are displayed also, however the functions for search and pagination are not working. The search returns No Match result however the record is present in the table. Can someone please tell me the error please.

```
<table id="Data_Table" width="100%">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <td>ID</td>
       <td>Employee Name</td>
       <td>Job Role</td>
       <td>Competency Level</td>
       <td>Action</td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
       <?php 
           if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
           foreach($result as $row) {
       ?>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <form method="post">
               <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['role']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['competency']; ?></td>
               <td>
                   <button type="button" class="view_emp" title="View Record">
                   <span class="la la-eye"></span> View
                   </button>
                   <button type="button" class="edit_emp" title="Update Record">
                   <span class="la la-edit"></span>Update
                   </button>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="keyToDelete" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" required>
                    <button type="submit" name="delete_employee" class="delete_employee" title="Delete Record"><span class="la la-trash"></span>Delete
                    </button>
                 </td>
               </form>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
     <?php
          }
        }                                                            
        else {
              echo "No Employee Record could be found";
             }

         $db-> close();
      ?>
</table>
```

In my code I have also included the script that would use DataTables as follows:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js" integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
```

and the style link for the datatable

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
```

All the style are working as intended but the function such as search and pagination are not working can someone tell me what i made wrong here

I defined the DataTables in my script as follows:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#Data_Table').DataTable(); 
    });                           
</script>
```

There are no error in the console log of the browser the function search and pagination simply wont work, search option will search and return results as No match with records when there is a record and $results are the data fetched from my database employees eg: id: 1 ,name: Bob ,role: Web Designer ,Competency: Beginner.

Comment: Show us (a) the contents of the `<script>...</script>` tag where your DataTable is defined; (b) some sample data from `$result`; (c) any error messages from your browser's console.

Comment: edit made showing the script where DataTable have been defined

Answer (score 1):

In order to use DataTables, you need to inizialize one

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   $('#Data_Table').DataTable();
});
```

This needs to be wrapped in a script tag

I don't see it anywhere in your code

Plus, you missed a td closing tag in Line 18

Here's a working example: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Trillyy/v3Lr0p5m/)

Source: [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Hello I have already inizialise the function and taken its id to my table tag and it is not working, without it I wouldnt be able to view the dataTable styling in my table

Comment: maybe it's because you missed a td closing tag after your form tag

Comment: I dont think so the button found in the last td tag have been closed and i only have 5 td tags -- Even after correcting that td tag in line 18 it still not working

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle example, without the php logic, if you look for something that does not exist the result will disappear and No Match text is shown

Comment: I see, that but if connected to a database the result will always be no match text why is it ?

Comment: as shown the code works fine with static data but why is it that it wont work when you connect it with mysql database and retrieve the data from the database

Comment: you need to provide database structure, queries you use, in order for someone to answer this question

Comment: what I can tell you right now is that I see a opening { but never see a closing }, maybe you can check this out

Comment: Edit was made and i have included the query and the rest of the code, static data works as shown by your example, however i need the dynamic data to work which is not working

Comment: When you inspect the page do you see the values in all the td's?

Comment: How can i check the values in my td's?? - The value seems to be present in all the td's and is displaying on the table also

Comment: right click on the table and click on inspect, php interpreter generates an html page, so if you find the values in the td's it is not a php problem

Comment: yeah i have inspected the td's values and all values fetched from db are present

Comment: if values are fetched, it's not a php problem, unless maybe there are some php errors in the page, but I doubt so

Comment: Even though I don't think its the mistake here, I wanted to add that you used mysqli_query (procedural style) and $db->close (oo style), you shoud pick one style and use it for everything

Comment: I think the error is due to dynamic data which could not be search by dataTable but im not sure

Comment: I don't think so, as I said before the php interpreter generates a static html page, so you shoud be able to use datatables with no problems

Comment: What seems to be the issue then ? Why is it when there is no database the functions are found ?

Comment: I don't really know, can't help you any further